# View that shows what's not imported yet

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a view that references 3 tables. The view is from the dbo.LoadedFiles table, where I manually insert filenames and filetypes.
The other two are dbo.LandingPages and dbo.ExitPages. Both of those have a FOREIGN KEY reference column from dbo.LoadedFiles ID called LoadedFile_id.

I want the view to show which LoadedFile has not yet been imported into my dbo.LandingPages and dbo.ExitPages tables.

Here is my code thus far, I know it's wrong, but just so you guys have reference.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_FilesNotYetLoaded]
AS
    SELECT
        lf.ID,
        filename,
        filetype
    FROM JPStarter.dbo.LoadedFiles lf
    JOIN JPStarter.staging.ExitPages AS ep ON lf.ID = ep.LoadedFile_id
    JOIN JPStarter.staging.LandingPages AS lp ON lf.ID = lp.LoadedFile_id
    WHERE lf.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM JPStarter.dbo.LoadedFiles
        )
```

Comment: Read about [left join.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join to the tables at all to give the desired result. Notice the `UNION` operator in the subquery.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_FilesNotYetLoaded]
AS
SELECT
    [ID]
   ,[filename]
   ,[filetype]
FROM
    [JPStarter].[dbo].[LoadedFiles]
WHERE
    [ID] NOT IN (
        SELECT
            [LoadedFile_id]
        FROM
            [JPStarter].[staging].[ExitPages]
        UNION
        SELECT
            [LoadedFile_id]
        FROM
            [JPStarter].[staging].[LandingPages]
    );
```